# inline JavaScript references

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a line in a `<script>` that populates a table. I would like to reference a changing value as illustrated by `tableData[i][j]`

e.g. `var tableData = [["www.google.com", "www.google.com"], ["www.apple.com", "www.apple.com"], ["www.microsoft.com", "www.microsoft.com"]]`

I don't know if its possible, If it is I know I am not doing it right.

`downloadCell.innerHTML = "<button class=\"example-btn\" onclick=\"location.href=" + tableData[i][j] + "\">Download</button>"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just make it `innerHTML = '<a class="example-btn" href="https://'+tableData[i][i]+'">Download</a>'` (and that's lacking proper escaping of the attribute already). Don't mess around with an `onclick` handler.

Comment: Please post the code of the whole script (including the loops over the array etc)

Comment: @Bergi will `[i][i]` work on 3rd item of array?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey oops, `[i][j]` of course

Answer (score 0):

These are mistakes in the code:

- As mentioned in the comments, append `https://` to the links for redirection.
- The `html` content should be appended, not overwritten in each iteration.
- It is cleaner to use template literals, in this case, to append the variables as follows.

```js
var tableData = [["www.google.com", "www.google.com"], ["www.apple.com", "www.apple.com"], ["www.microsoft.com", "www.microsoft.com"]];
for(let i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++)
    for(let j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++)
         downloadCell.innerHTML += `<button class="example-btn" onclick="location.href='https://${tableData[i][j]}'">Download</button>`;
```

```html
<div id="downloadCell"></div>
```

Comment: isn't it cleaner to use `createElement`?